# Setting drawable with colors to a TextView for supporting multiple themes

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes, attr

I want to have a list of CardViews like this, for my two themes:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0VqA.jpg

I want to have different background colors for textviews for each theme.
So, in my row xml, I have the following for the TextView:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtTipListId"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="17"
      android:background="@drawable/idcardview"
      android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
      android:textColor="@color/colorShadowInverse"
      android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
      android:textStyle="bold" />`
```

and the drawable "idcardview.xml" is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="?attr/themedCardBackgroundColor"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

and in the attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="themedCardBackgroundColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

and in the styles:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="themedCardBackgroundColor">@color/colorShadowInverse</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="themedCardBackgroundColor">@color/colorShadow</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and in the colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#F57C00</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#FFE0B2</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF5252</color>

<color name="colorShadow">#E0E0E0</color>
<color name="colorShadowInverse">#181818</color>

</resources>
```

When I run the app and go to the list activity, it gets the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class TextView

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/idcardview.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02003b

at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)

at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)

at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
```

but when I change the "idcardview.xml" solid color to just one color (for example, #181818), the app just runs fine. But I want it to change background color for light and dark theme.
Using Android Studio, min Sdk 11, target SDK 22.

Comment: I found this workaround in a comment, but I couldn't do it:
Using a theme attribute inside a color selector XML file is only supported in the most recent versions of Android. To overcome this limitation you need to create one color selector file for each theme, and fill them with plain colors. Then create a theme attribute which points to the correct color selector depending on the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my problem is solved.
The Problem was with themes defined in styles.xml.
I deleted this part:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

so after this, I have two custom themes and now when I use attributes in xmls, no error happens.
I created two drawables for each TextView with solid colors, Because I needed to round corners of the background, One for light theme and the other for dark theme.
Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.